# Bounded Loss Function Proof (Hoeffding's Inequalities)

Tags: loss-functions

Let $ h \in \{ -1, 1\}^X $ be a fixed hypothesis and $ S \sim D^m $,

where:

$h$ = predictor
$S$ = training sample
$D$ = probability distribution
$m$ = sample size
$X$ = domain / feature space
$L_D$ = risk of predictor $h$ / generalization error
$L_S$ = empirical risk
$\epsilon > 0$

Then $ P_S(|L_D(h) - L_S(h)| > \epsilon) \leq 2\ exp(-2m \epsilon^2)$

Is there anyone can help to prove the statement?

Comment: A proof would require clear definitions of *all* the symbols you are using.  Could you provide some?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear definitions. I have added definition for each symbol. @whuber